# Sample scene doesn't load

Tags: unity-game-engine

Over night there was a power outage and when I went to open my project the main camera and canvas were gone. However, my animator window, files, and scripts are all still there. As you can see below, all my files are there but my scene is not there where it says untitled all the way to the left. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I've added you the Unity3D tag, so not everyone has to check the image linked.

Comment: It doesn't load because there is no sample scene. Did you forget to save your scene before that power outage? Or have you tried to even open that scene from the file?

Comment: A number of things can go wrong with power outage. Do you have a backup? This might be the lesson you needed if you don't. Just Git It.

Comment: Go to the folder `Assets/Scenes` find your scene and double-click it?

Comment: Thank you Tom for adding me, I am at my high school working on the project and not at my house. My senior year computer class offers you to work on a project for the whole year so I am making a game. I think there might be a 3-5 day back up but I am not sure if they supply a back up to each individual student's U drive, but my teacher is checking with the IT guys now, thanks for the help.

Comment: I also went to folder Assets/Scenes as derHugo suggested and it was actually the correct scene, but it says it was last edited on 9/10/19 4:00 am, this is way off however. I didn't even create the project until late September. So there is a problem with my saving. Even though I saved my game on a regular basis it does not say that I have ever saved, what is even weirder is that the scene file says it was edited before the project was even created.